# Removing last class through jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

ok i make it simple i have number of code like this:

```
<span class="baba">aaaa</span>
<span class="baba">aaaa</span>
<span class="baba">aaaa</span>
.
.
.
.
.
<span class="baba">aaaa</span>
```

I just want to use jquery to remove the last `<span class="baba">aaaa</span>`
how can i do that

Comment: @elclanrs, actually the English was my barrier to help the guy, there is too much "noise" in the question.

Comment: there is no noise in the question. i just want to remove the class by using jquery. This class is being repeated on the page. i just want to remove the last call of the that class

Comment: rewrite the question in comprehensible sentences then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('span.st_facebook_buttons:last').remove();
```

Comment: no, i tried that but it remove all the codes having class st_facebook_buttons

Comment: i just want the last code to be removed

Comment: @gdoron It was an oversight. I was a victim of directly copy-pasting the original excerpt without realizing there was already a `remove()` call there.

Comment: It's o.k. downvote reverted. I would even upvoted it as it looks right now, but... I couldn't read the question until the end and the OP says it didn't help him...